# How to order a data.table in R based on multiple columns with ties?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm fairly new to data.table and have a basic question. I'm trying to reorder the following data table based the two columns.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(letter=c('a','a','a','a','b','b','c','d','d','d','d'),  
                 value =c(1,2,4,8,2,5,1,1,2,3,9))

        letter value
 1:      a     1
 2:      a     2
 3:      a     4
 4:      a     8
 5:      b     2
 6:      b     5
 7:      c     1
 8:      d     1
 9:      d     2
10:      d     3
11:      d     9
```

I want to sort the letters based on the lowest associated value, should they be equal the next value (if available) should be compared and so on.

This should produce the following result:

```
    letter value
 1:      c     1
 2:      d     1
 3:      d     2
 4:      d     3
 5:      d     9
 6:      a     1
 7:      a     2
 8:      a     4
 9:      a     8
10:      b     2
11:      b     5
```

I have tried `DT[order(value), .SD, letter]` which does sort on value, but does not take subsequent values into account in case of ties at the lowest associated value. I feel there should be an easy way to do this but I can't find the answer. Thanks.

Comment: So you would like to sort first on "value" and then on letter? What about setorder(DT, value, -letter) ?

Comment: No, I would like to get the letter with the lowest value followed by all the other values of that letter. Then moving on to the letter with the next lowest value and get all rows with that letter. In case of ties, subsequent values of a letter have to be compared. Sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to sort the letters based on the lowest associated value, should they be equal the next value (if available) should be compared and so on.

That's not so simple. First, we need to pad out the data so that the "second" value for `c` is `1` again; and the third; and the fourth:

```
n = max(DT[, .N, by=letter]$N)
oDT = DT[, .(rid = 1:n, v = c(value, rep(value[.N], n-.N))), by=letter]
```

Then, I think we need a recursive function to check ties:

```
chk_ties = function(L, r, maxr = n){
    if (r == maxr) 
        L
    else
        oDT[letter %in% L & rid == r, {
            if (.N > 1L)
                chk_ties(letter, r + 1L)
            else
                letter
        }, keyby=v]$V1
}

chk_ties(unique(DT$letter), 1L)
# [1] "c" "d" "a" "b"
```

Or, instead of the recursive function, I realized we can make this hack:

```
setorderv(dcast(oDT, letter ~ rid), as.character(1:n))$letter
# [1] "c" "d" "a" "b"
```

Finally, we need to join on that, as in @lmo's answer:

```
DT[setorderv(dcast(oDT, letter ~ rid), as.character(1:n))$letter, on="letter"]
# or
DT[chk_ties(unique(DT$letter), 1L), on=.(letter)]
```

One can write `on=.(letter)` or `on="letter"` here.

Comment: Great answer as always !

Comment: @sandrjekk Glad to hear it. Fyi, it's good that you updated the question with a more illustrative example, but it's polite to ping folks who already posted an answer letting them know (by commenting under their answer). Anyway, I just commented on lmo's now.